# $1+ab$ is a unit if and only if $1+ba$ is a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $a,b \in R$ then prove that $1+ab$ is a unit if and only if $1+ba$ is a unit and find the inverse.

Then there exist an element say $s \in R$ such that $(1+ab)s =1$ then from here how will I approach to find the inverse of $1+ba$??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since $1+ab$ is a unit in $R$, there exists an inverse $s$ such that

$$ (1+ab)s = s(1+ab) = 1. $$

Now let $t = 1 - bsa$. Then

\begin{align*}
t(1+ba)
&= 1 + ba - bsa - bsaba \\
&= 1 + ba - bs(1+ab)a \\
&= 1 + ba - ba \\
&= 1
\end{align*}

and likewise for $(1+ba)t$. So $1+ba$ is also a unit with the inverse $1-bsa$.

**My intuition.** Formally and heuristically, the inverse $s$ of $1+ab$ is

$$ s = (1+ab)^{-1} = 1 - ab + (ab)^2 - (ab)^3 + \cdots. $$

Likewise, if $1+ba$ has an inverse, it will have a formal expansion

\begin{align*}
(1+ba)^{-1}
&= 1 - ba + (ba)^2 - (ba)^3 + \cdots \\
&= 1 - b(1 - ab + (ab)^2 - \cdots)a \\
&= 1 - bsa.
\end{align*}

Then we can begin the actual proof with this guess.

Comment: how will i understand that i have to take t=1-bsa??